# How do I compare something to something that's already been printed?

Tags: java, compare, equals, compareto

I'm writing a code that requires input from a user (their name). I want to put in something that will compare each name to the names before so that no name is printed twice (so if someone typed in John Smith twice, it would print something saying 'that name's already been used, try again'). My teacher told us to use the methods equals or compareTo, but I'm not sure how. Some of my code is below:

```
while (name <= 32)
    {
        System.out.println ("Type your first name.");
        String firstName=input.nextLine();

        System.out.println ();

        System.out.println ("Now type your last name.");
        String lastName=input.nextLine();

        if ((firstName + lastName).equals(firstName + lastName))
        {
            System.out.println ("That is not your name. Please type in your real name.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println (firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
```

Obviously what I did there doesn't work (using the equals method). Does anyone know a method that can help?

Comment: store the already entered names into something like an array, an arraylist or probably even better: a Set.

Answer (score 0):

In your task, first of all, think about the main idea:

1. You want to enter names.
2. You want to compare them for each other.

Well, the first task is easy, and you've made it :)

The second task needs some clarification on it. As you almost tried, you can only check the previous name. If you want to compare every new name with the names before, you have to somehow store them. See, a computer is stupid you have to tell it every command to achieve your goal (create algorithm for your task).

So, the algorithm or steps for your task are:

1. Decide, where to store your data (names) | Java has data storages like: simple arrays and more advanced structures like lists, sets etc.
2. Create empty storage  | You have to prepare your empty storage. Just initialize it
3. Create some loop, where you will enter names | With ending condition of course (32 times)
4. In your loop, enter name
5. Check it | So, as I said before comp. is absolutely stupid, even if at first your storage is empty and everytime your enter name you need to go through your storage (with another loop), compare with every name (if exists) and there, if you suddenly meet the same name you have to try again and go to the 4th step. Otherwise, if the name does not exist in your storage you have place it, in order to check for another duplicate in future!
6. Work until your loops end!

That is it! Little tutorial with the homework for you)
So your homework is to implement this algorithm above.
I think for now, your teacher had to tell you about Arrays?

For the 5th step there are even crazy way to check names if you don't know about data structures. You can create some String variable, where you will store the names with some tricky way like: "'John Smith' 'Allien Wood'". Next you have to go through this possible huge string every time you entering new name and check it for its substrings. Tricky-Freaky!

Answer (score 0):

this should be a solution for you, if I understood your question.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    boolean access;

    while (true) {
        access = true;
        System.out.println("Type your first name.");
        String firstName = input.readLine();

        //System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Now type your last name.");
        String lastName = input.readLine();

        String fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        if(names.size()==0) {
            names.add(fullName);
            continue;
        }
        for (String name : names) {
            if (name.equals(fullName)) {
                System.out.println("That is not your name. Please type in your real name.");
                access = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(access) {
            names.add(fullName);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
    }
```